# How to use Route 53 and VPS service of aws to run my website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vps, amazon-route53

I have my domain name in godaddy's account. And I want to host that site on `aws`.

So for that I have created the `EC2` instance and it is working fine with the public address they have given

http://ec2-23-20-10-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

I want to open the same thing with my domain name. How can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need more context on this. Does Route 53 already have control of your domain name?

If your domain is in Route 53 and the NS (nameserver) values are using AWS name servers, then the process of routing your EC2 enviornment to your domain is quite easy.

In that case, all youll do is a create an A-level record set with the alias target of your raw EC2 url. Normally you set your A-level record set to be DOMAINNAME.com ...

After that, for posterity and canonical redirect purposes--you'd create a CNAME record for www.DOMAINNAME.com...this could point to your A-level record set of DOMAINNAME.com...

Hopes this helps!

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your web server responds on domain.com
- Point your DNS record (root records and/or www record) to the web server I.P